# Search inside a text file for certain values

Tags: c#

I have a requirement when I have a bunch of files in a folder and I need to identify some files which match up particular search criteria.

My file contents are as below

```
<app>1.0 <app>
<name> Test Name <name>
```

My requirement is to go inside these folders and check for files that match particular search criteria.
eg. app=1.0 and name='Test Name'

Comment: Are you searching for files by name or by content? What have you tried?

Comment: A utility called SearchMyFiles by Nir Sofer would do this without any coding

Comment: Are they always XML files? You can use the XMLDocument class and find using XPath.

Comment: I used regex to do this but didn't reach anywhere

Comment: Can you show us the code using regex that did not work?

Comment: Those are not xml files. Its a text files with tags

Comment: t = @"\s+(</(?:" + token + ")>)|(<(?:" + token + @")>)\s+";

Comment: You could surround it with a root tag and treat it as an XML text. `<root><app>1.0 <app>
<name> Test Name <name></root>`. See [XDocument.Parse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Linq_XDocument_Parse_System_String_).

Comment: `<(?<key>\w+)>\s*(?<value>[^<]*)\s*<\1>` will get you all the key/values

Comment: Is there any way we could do that using LINQ?

Comment: Oh, Thanks Robert. I will try that

Comment: You could use LINQ with my suggestion above; however, I just see that your tags are not closed as they should be in XML. They should be like `<app>1.0 </app>` with the `/` in the closing tag.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of doing it.  Of course if you are going to be doing a lot of searches, then use the dictionary method.

```
void Main()
{
    var source = @"<app>1.0 <app>
<name> Test Name <name>";
    var regex = new Regex(@"<(?<key>\w+)>\s*(?<value>[^<]*)\s*<\1>");

    var matches = regex.Matches(source)
      .Cast<Match>()
      .Select(m=>new KeyValuePair<string,string>(m.Groups["key"].Value, m.Groups["value"].Value));

    // Your test here
    if (matches.Any(kvp=>kvp.Key == "app" && kvp.Value == "1.0"))
    {     
      //...
    }

    /* Here is the dictionary way */
    var matchDict = regex.Matches(source)
      .Cast<Match>()
      .ToDictionary(m=>m.Groups["key"].Value, m=>m.Groups["value"].Value);

    // Your dict test here
    if (matchDict["app"] == "1.0")
    {
      //...
    }
}
```

Comment: If you really wanted to use Linq you could convert this into a method you could call from a Linq Where statement, passing in a dictionary of keys and values that need to exist/match to return true.

Comment: Thanks Robert and everyone who helped me with this